# How to return random dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, random

Is it possible to return a dictionary this way?
i guess it's just some syntax i got wrong.

```
struct Dare {
  var theDare: [String: String, String: Bool;] = [
    ["dare": "Dare1",
     "darePerson": true],
    ["dare": "Dare2",
     "darePerson": false],
    ["dare": "Dare3",
     "darePerson": false],
    ["dare": "Dare4",
     "darePerson": true],
    ["dare": "Dare5",
     "darePerson": false]
]

func randomDare() -> Dictionary<String, Bool> {
    return theDare[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quotesArray.count)))]
}

}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list of dictionaries is not declared correctly. Instead of being :

```
var theDare: [String: String, String: Bool;]
```

It should be :

```
var theDare: [[String: AnyObject]]
```

as you always have `String` keys but sometimes have `String` values and sometimes `Bool` values.

Your `randomDare()` function return needs to be changed accordingly to :

```
func randomDare() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Comment: Worked lige a charm! Thanks!

Comment: If it works for you, you can just accept the answer, this is all the thanks that's needed ;-) Enjoy coding